# Dynamically Create Excel file using C#.net and Microsoft Excel Interop?

Tags: c#-4.0, excel-2007

I'm creating Excel like following:

```
     class Program
{
    private Excel.Application app = null;
    private Excel.Application worksheet = null;
    private Excel.Application workbook = null;
    private Excel.Application worksheet_range = null;

    //public Program()
    //{
    //    CreateExcelDoc();
    //}
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program obj = new Program();
        obj.CreateExcelDoc();
    }

    public void CreateExcelDoc()
    {
        try
        {
            app = new Excel.Application();
            if (app == null)
                return;
            app.Visible = true;
            workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(1);////error in this,saying "can not convert from Excel.Workbook to Excel.Application"

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("CreateExcelDoc: Error" + ex.Message);
        }

    }
}
```

Could anyone pl tell where I'm going wrong?
Note: I'm following this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173186%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Please send me any nice link/solution. I'm using Windows 7 64-bit OS.

Thanks.

Comment: Where do you declare the variable `workbook` and what type do you declare it as?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this declaration:

```
    private Excel.Application app = null;
    private Excel.Application worksheet = null;
    private Excel.Application workbook = null;
    private Excel.Application worksheet_range = null;
```

to:

```
    private Excel.Application app = null;
    private Excel.Worksheet worksheet = null;
    private Excel.Workbook workbook = null;
    private Excel.Range worksheet_range = null;
```

You may also follow exactly the code:

```
    app.Visible = true; // or false if you don't want to show app.
    workbook  = app.Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
    worksheet = (Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets[1];

    // Select the Excel cells, in the range c1 to c7 in the worksheet.
    worksheet_range  = worksheet.get_Range("C1", "C7");
```

**Edit**

You can save your workbook with the following code:

```
    workbook.SaveAs(@"C:\XMLCopy.xls",
    Excel.XlFileFormat.xlXMLSpreadsheet, missing, missing,
    false, false, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
    missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);
```

but look for resources release methods after Workbook save. You need to close your file, your Application and all the involved objects.

Comment: Thank you! Now, no error and I can proceed.I hope with this I can create Excel Dynamically?

Comment: I do not want to make it visible, but rather to save dynamically it in particular location in disk drive.How can I do this? Also, next time when I'm going to create it application should check if the file exist or not.

Comment: These are simple task you can achieve with a little bit of MSDN and Google search. To hide your app just set app.Visible = false. For the other tasks check the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/h1e33e36.aspx